# Subquery Executing Problems

Tags: sql

The code below is correct as it show me

```
SELECT TOP 3 P.CategoryID,SUM(OD.Quantity) From "Order Details" AS OD
            INNER JOIN
            Products AS P
            ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
            GROUP BY P.CategoryID
            ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity) DESC
```

The result is

```
CategoryID   sum
1            9532
4            9149
3            7906
```

but I encountered this error when I try to subquery it.

The code below is the current problem that cause the error. The error is 
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

```
SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID =
    (
    SELECT TOP 3 P.CategoryID,SUM(OD.Quantity) From "Order Details" AS OD
    INNER JOIN
    Products AS P
    ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
    GROUP BY P.CategoryID
    ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity) DESC
    )
```

I am not sure how to solve it or change the code in any way and I did try to not to group the categoryID which was a failure as it did not even show any result.

The desired result should be

```
CategoryName     
Beverages
Dairy Products
Confections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses LIMIT, not TOP. This Issue is tagged with MySQL, not SQL Server, so I'm answering accordingly.

```
SELECT
  P.CategoryID, SUM( OD.Quantity )
FROM
  OrderDetails AS OD
  INNER JOIN Products AS P
    ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
GROUP BY
  P.CategoryID
ORDER BY
  SUM( OD.Quantity ) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

In the spirit of what @Kjell suggests, MySQL doesn't allow the IN Predicate this way. Use INNER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT
  CategoryName
FROM
  Categories
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      P.CategoryID, SUM( OD.Quantity )
    FROM
      OrderDetails AS OD
      INNER JOIN Products AS P
        ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
    GROUP BY
      P.CategoryID
    ORDER BY
      SUM( OD.Quantity ) DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ) AS Quants
  ON Quants.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID;
```

If you are using SQL Server, please update your question and either use an IN predicate or use the INNER JOIN example with TOP instead of LIMIT:

```
SELECT
  CategoryName
FROM
  Categories
WHERE
  CategoryID IN
  (
    SELECT TOP 3
      P.CategoryID
    FROM
      OrderDetails AS OD
      INNER JOIN Products AS P
        ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
    GROUP BY
      P.CategoryID
    ORDER BY
      SUM( OD.Quantity )
  )
```

-- OR

```
SELECT
  CategoryName
FROM
  Categories
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT TOP 3
      P.CategoryID, SUM( OD.Quantity ) AS q
    FROM
      OrderDetails AS OD
      INNER JOIN Products AS P
        ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
    GROUP BY
      P.CategoryID
    ORDER BY
      SUM( OD.Quantity )
  ) AS Quants
  ON Quants.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
```

Comment: Sorry for putting mysql tag but overall thanks for the help,the 3th sql code was the correct one but I did minor change by changing the ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity) DESC WHICH got my desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "CategoryID = " to "CategoryID IN"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `where CategoryID =
    (  SELECT Top 3......`

You are using = for comparison which means subquery should return exactly one categoryid 
But here you are anyways selecting Top 3 , hence the error is coming.

Use `IN` instead of `=`  in where clause this should solve that error.

Answer (score 0):

You should not select SUM(OD.Quantity) in the inner query.

```
    SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID IN
            (
            SELECT TOP 3 P.CategoryID From "Order Details" AS OD
            INNER JOIN
            Products AS P
            ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID
            GROUP BY P.CategoryID
            ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity) DESC
            )
```